# Android JSONObject skipping null value while creating

Tags: android, json, android-json

I want to send `JSONObject` from mobile to server in `Android`. There are some `null` values which also i want to send.

I have tried following both way but its **SKIPPING** `NULL` values.

```
tempJsonValuesOrder.put(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_OTHERS, orderCursor.isNull(orderCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_OTHERS)) ? null :orderCursor.getString(orderCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_OTHERS)));
```

Is there any way to put `null` value in `JSONObject`?

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @SpringBreaker I have edited with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all i found solution like:

```
tempJsonValuesOrder.put(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_TRANSPORT, orderCursor.isNull(orderCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_TRANSPORT)) ? "" :orderCursor.getString(orderCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_TRANSPORT)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting those values to empty Strings, if it is suitable.